# What will be the output of this simple program and why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div w3-test-directive></div>
    <div w3-test-directivee ></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
        return {
            template : "howw!"
        };
    });
</script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.directive("w3TestDirectivee", function() {
        return {
            template : "hie how are you!"
        };
    });
</script>
```

Which template will be returned? I have two scripts: which one will be called and why ?

Comment: second template is returned. but i dont knw how it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the second parameter in the second `angular.module` call, and it will work as you expected. See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) for the second parameter:

```
If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further configuration.
```

Since you provided the second parameter, a new `myApp` module is created every time overwriting whatever is defined before.

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div w3-test-directive></div>
    <div w3-test-directivee ></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
        return {
            template : "howw!"
        };
    });
</script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp");
    app.directive("w3TestDirectivee", function() {
        return {
            template : "hie how are you!"
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the use of parameters ?

Comment: @PadmeshKannan that array is used for loading dependency modules like ngRouter (or some modules you wrote yourself). You declare the dependencies when you define your module. When you retrieve your module, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the multiple definition of app module, which is removing first directive for define app.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div w3-test-directive></div>
    <div w3-test-directivee></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.directive("w3TestDirective", function () {
        alert("w3TestDirective called");
        return {
            template: "howw!"
        };
    });
</script>
<script>
   // var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.directive("w3TestDirectivee", function () {
        alert("w3TestDirectivee called");
        return {
            template: "hie how are you!"
        };
    });
</script>
```